# Display data from useSelector

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Using redux and passing data to store from one component i am then trying to add the object to an array in another component in order to display a table. I can see the data in the console but cant assign it or get it to display correctly. UPDATE When i log my data i see it as follows

```
   {'0':{'key':0, 'name':'somename'}}
```

I can access it if i throw it into a variable, but why does it show up an as object in that format?

```
  interface DataType {
  key: React.Key;
  name: string;
  }

 const originalRow = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.dataType);
 console.log(originalRow) // this shows my data 
 {0: {...}}
 0: {key:'1', name: 'some name' ...}
```

I have tried setting my array as

```
   const originalRow = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.dataType);
   const [myrows1, setmyRows] = useState<DataType[]>([originalRow as DataType])
```

also in

```
useEffect(() => {
 setmyRows([originalRow])
 setmyRows([...myrows1, originalRow])
```

my reducer looks as follows

```
  export interface DataTypeAction{
  type: string;
  payload: DataType | null
 }

export const RowReducer = (state : DataType| null = null, action: DataTypeAction) : 
 DataType | null => {
  switch(action.type){
      case ROW_TYPE:
        console.log("user reducer", action.payload);
          return action.payload
          default: 
          return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you're confusing local and global state. The useState hook doesn't connect to Redux, it only provides a local state value (available only in the component where the hook is called). Your console log isn't getting hit, right? You need to dispatch an action in order to get the data into your reducer.

Comment: Yup, this is after ive called the reducer and now am in another component trying to get that data

Comment: @Abe the console does log the data correctly. I can see the object I just can’t add it into the array.